# Add date to EditText with setText onCreate

Tags: android, datetime, settext

So I have been trying to get this to work two different way.

The first is this:

```
EditText dod = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dod); 

SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());
dod.setText(currentDateandTime);
```

I am getting error:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
```

The second way to try to solve it was this:

```
    int mYear,mMonth,mDay;

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.getDefault());
    mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    dod.setText(new StringBuilder().append(mDay).append("-").append(mMonth+1).append("-").append(mYear));
```

Getting the same error here, and this is working on kikat 4.4 so I dont get the problem, the EditText is declared and all.

Comment: check dod EditText because seems that is null!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No matter which method you use to set the text, you will get error because you either

1. You have the following code before `setContentView` in `onCreate`.

   ```
   EditText dod = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.dod);
   ```
2. Or `R.id.dob` is not available inside the layout you are using in `setConentView`.

Comment: I have the code after onCreate and setContentView. And the id is inside the displayed layout

Comment: @alexandermogren: Please post the complete code of this class and xml layout used.

Comment: I have solved it and thanks for the help. I took a extra look at the setContentView and it is firsts set the activity_main layout

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because your still object hasn't been constructed.

Replace `String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(new Date());`

with `String currentDateandTime = new String(sdf.format(new Date()));`

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is most likely because you haven't assign the ID of 'dod' to an `EditText` in your XML layout file.